# Confused about Orthographic Projection of camera in SceneKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, opengl-es, scenekit

I want to use orthographic projection to display 3D scene in my app. In my code I put a box in scene and set orthographic projection of Point of view like blow. Camera at (0,0,500) look at -z direction, and box at origin of world. So camera should be able to capture the box.

```
let cameraNode = SCNNode()
let pov = SCNCamera()
pov.usesOrthographicProjection = true
let width = UISreen.main.bounds.size.width
let glMat = GLKMatrix4MakeOrtho(-width/2, width/2, -width/2, width/2, 1, 1000)
pov.projectionTransform = SCNMatrix4FromGLKMatrix4(glMat)
cameraNode.camera = pov
cameraNode.position = SCNVector3.init(0, 0, 500)
scene.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)

let boxGeo = SCNBox.init(width: 100, height: 100, length: 1, chamferRadius: 0)
let box = SCNNode.init(geometry: boxGeo)
scene.rootNode.addChildNode(box)
```

But I can see nothing. I find out If set `orthographicScale` to `width/2.0` will works correctly.

```
pov.orthographicScale = Double(width/2);
```

**Question 1 :** I don't know why this works. I read docs of apple but still confused. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scncamera/1436612-orthographicscale?language=objc

> **orthographicScale**
>
> Specifies the camera’s magnification factor when using an orthographic projection.

Why I need magnify orthographic projection? I already set the dimension of it through `GLKMatrix4MakeOrtho`.

I'm not sure whether it is relate to viewport transform? Because viewport transform in OpenGL computed as follows: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/opengl/glviewport

[image]

**Question 2 :** I also find If I create projection matrix like blow it works same as before.

```
let glMat = GLKMatrix4MakeOrtho(0, width, 0, width, 1, 1000)
```

In OpenGL it means different viewing box and will display different partition of scene.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Where does your camera look at? Do you set the viewport?

Comment: Camera look at -z direction. I don't explicit set viewport in SceneKit.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose, you can't see your 3D objects in the scene using `GLKMatrix4MakeOrtho`, due to the fact that so many classes of GLKit for iOS and macOS are deprecated now.

In order to see your 3D object, you need to manually set **`Far Z Clipping`** parameter in `Attributes Inspector`. These two fields are **`near`** and **`far`** clipping planes of the frustum of your Orthographic Camera. A default value of `Far=100` doesn't allow you see the scene further than 100 units away.

[image]

> Then use a `Scale` property to set a scale factor for your objects in an ortho view.

In order to use it programmatically via `GLKMatrix4MakeOrtho`, you need to import `GLKit` and `OpenGL` modules (as well as all the necessary delegate protocols) into your project at first.

```
import GLKit
import OpenGL

// Obj-C GLKMatrix4

GLK_INLINE GLKMatrix4 GLKMatrix4MakeOrtho(float left, 
                                          float right,
                                          float bottom, 
                                          float top,
                                          float nearZ, 
                                          float farZ) {
    float ral = right + left;
    float rsl = right - left;
    float tab = top + bottom;
    float tsb = top - bottom;
    float fan = farZ + nearZ;
    float fsn = farZ - nearZ;

    GLKMatrix4 m = { 2.0f / rsl, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
                     0.0f, 2.0f / tsb, 0.0f, 0.0f,
                     0.0f, 0.0f, -2.0f / fsn, 0.0f,
                     -ral / rsl, -tab / tsb, -fan / fsn, 1.0f };

    return m;
}
```

> Also, on iOS, GLKit requires an OpenGL ES 2.0 context. In macOS, GLKit requires an OpenGL context that supports the OpenGL 3.2 Core Profile.

But remember! Many GL Features are deprecated, so you'd better use **`Metal`** framework. [Look at deprecated classes of GLKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/glkit).

Comment: Yes I find it will be 100 default. But why I set projectionTransform which already specify zNear and zFar not change the camera z clipping?

Comment: Set it to, at least, `700` at first. Is it working now? Do not apply any math to your Camera. let's just see if it's working now.

Comment: Yes It works. So the zNear and zFar of orthographic projection isn't related to zNear and zFar of camera?

Comment: You mean that you've set programmatically? It's hard to say, I don't see your full project... Why are you using `GLKMatrix4MakeOrtho`?

Comment: I want to create a viewing box of orthographic projection that just capture partition of scene. Full projection matrix is created by `GLKMatrix4MakeOrtho`.

Comment: OpenGL is deprecated, but the parts of GLKit being used here are just math. `GLKMatrix4MakeOrtho` is just a shorthand for [math you could do yourself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthographic_projection) which is equally valid regardless of whether you use the resulting matrix with SceneKit, GL, Metal, or whatever else. (Sorry, can’t dive enough into your issue to solve it right now, but at least I can flag what’s *not* the problem.)

Comment: Setting zNear and zFar on the camera is part of how the camera calculates its own *perspective* projection matrix. If you’re using ortho projection, clipping distances are part of the matrix you calculate yourself.

Comment: _“you need to import GLKit and OpenGL modules”_ This is not the problem.  The project would not compile if it were.  If it's not explicitly included, but it's still compiling, Xcode is auto-linking those frameworks for you (the `CLANG_MODULES_AUTOLINK` build setting, by default enabled).  You can't compile/link using functions you aren't linking to, in any IDE/compiler.

Comment: _“due to the fact that so many classes of GLKit for iOS and macOS are deprecated now”_ Also not the issue.  Deprecated does *not* mean broken, disabled, removed, or otherwise— it means “marked for removal in future versions, but for now still works as it always has”.  The proof here is the large number of games on the iOS App Store and on macOS (App Store, Steam, etc.) that still use OpenGL and still work just as well as they always have.  You probably _should_ switch to Metal, but there's no technical reason why OpenGL doesn't work on Apple platforms the same as it always has.

Comment: @AndyFedoroff Hi, would you be able to take a look on my ARKit related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62783206/projecting-the-arkit-face-tracking-3d-mesh-to-2d-image-coordinates ? Thanks for your time!!

Comment: Hi @swiftlearneer! I'm not good at Metal but I'll try.

Comment: Hi @AndyFedoroff! Thanks for your response! I am just wondering my post might be a bit confusing. And I posted the code on GitHub already. So this way might be more understandable for my question: https://github.com/andrewcccc/Ftrack/tree/master/FaceCapturedata-master?

Comment: Hi @AndyFedoroff! I am just wondering did you get any progress earlier? I wonder whether you would have some insights to just access the ARKit parameters instead. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62867707/swift-access-to-arkit-camera-parameters-and-save-them?

Comment: Hi @swiftlearneer, Sorry I am not succeed in what you needed. Almost all of the accessible intrinsic ARCamera parameters are just gettable. The other parameters aren't accessible at all.

Comment: @AndyFedoroff, No worries! Thank you so much for your time!! I was planning to get all the parameters so that I can confirm whether those 3D mesh face vertices make sense or not. If you don't mind, do you have a minutes on how to get those intrinsic ARCamera parameters and save them? I only know of this var intrinsics: simd_float3x3 { get }. Should I just print that? Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62623726/what-is-the-real-focal-length-of-the-camera-used-in-realitykit/62627471#62627471

Comment: You can print it this way – `print(sceneView.session.currentFrame?.camera.intrinsics)`.

Comment: And look at this post : https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/strings/how-to-save-a-string-to-a-file-on-disk-with-writeto

Comment: @AndyFedoroff can you take a look at my question and help me about orthographic camera position? Thanks very much. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65503089