# ARKIT 2.0 - ARImageTrackingConfiguration

Tags: ios, swift, arkit

I have an app which detects a few images and do some effects (mostly play a video inside the image)
as long as the func renderer is triggered when a Image is detected, is there any func that is triggered when no Image is detected?

When no image is detected I would like to stop the video playing.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you have a look at the documentation you will see that an `ARImageAnchor` conforms to the `ARTrackable Protocol` which:

> is adopted by ARKit classes, such as the ARFaceAnchor class, that
>   represent moving objects in a scene.
>
> ARSCNView and ARSKView automatically hide the nodes for anchors whose
>   isTracked property is false.
>
> ARKit automatically manages representations of such objects in an
>   active AR session, ensuring that changes in the real-world object's
>   position and orientation (the transform property for anchors) are
>   reflected in corresponding ARKit objects. The isTracked property
>   indicates whether the current transform is valid with respect to
>   movement of the real-world object.

As such you can detect if your ARImageAnchor is currently being tracked using something like this as a starter:

```
//--------------------------
//MARK: -  ARSessionDelegate
//--------------------------

extension ViewController: ARSessionDelegate{

    func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate anchors: [ARAnchor]) {

        //1. Enumerate Our Anchors To See If We Have Found Our Target Anchor
        for anchor in anchors{

            if let imageAnchor = anchor as? ARImageAnchor, imageAnchor == videoAnchor{

                //2. If The ImageAnchor Is No Longer Tracked Then Handle The Event
                if !imageAnchor.isTracked{

                }else{


                }
            }
        }
     }
}
```

Whereby `videoAnchor` is simply an `ARImageAnchor` I have stored reference to as a `Global Variable`.

Alternatively you if you want to cancel an operation when a particular `SCNNode` is outside of the `Frostrum` of the camera you can do something like so:

```
/// Stops All VideoPlayers Outside Of Frostrum
///
/// - Parameter currentVideoNode: SCNNode
func stopAllVideoPlayersOutsideOfPointOfView(){

    //a. Get The Current Point Of You & Our SCNScene
    guard let currentPointOfView = self.augmentedRealityView?.pointOfView,
          let scnView = self.augmentedRealityView else { return }

    //b. Loop Through All The Hierachy
    if let childNodes = self.augmentedRealityView?.scene.rootNode.childNodes{

        childNodes.forEach { (node) in

            //c. If Our Node Isn't In View Of The Camera Then Stop The Video
            if !scnView.isNode(node, insideFrustumOf: currentPointOfView){


            }
        }

    }
}
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: Sorry to bother you…… I'm struggling with a SceneKit problem could you help me out? Question:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52428397/confused-about-orthographic-projection-of-camera-in-scenekit

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have tried your code, but looks like it never gets triggered, I guess I am doing something wrong. I added it just before the view controller class and replace the logic for a simply print("I am IN"). var imageAnchor = [ARImageAnchor]()

extension ViewController: ARSessionDelegate{
    
    func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate anchors: [ARAnchor]) {
        
        //1. Enumerate Our Anchors To See If We Have Found Our Target Anchor
        for anchor in anchors{
            
            print("I am IN")

            }
        }
    
}

Comment: Have you set the ARSession delegate?

Comment: `var imageAnchor = [ARImageAnchor]()

extension ViewController: ARSessionDelegate{
    
    func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate anchors: [ARAnchor]) {
        
        //1. Enumerate Our Anchors To See If We Have Found Our Target Anchor
        for anchor in anchors{
            
            print("I am IN")

            }
        }
    
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, ARSCNViewDelegate {`